# Basic utility to read files with browse option

Tags: mac, finder, utilities

Newbie to Mac. I am trying to open a file under /usr folder using Atom editor. 
File path : /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3/libexec/conf

I am not able to find an option like windows browse where I can type/paste the file or directory name.

Another option that I am missing is the ability to open files from the network directly from the internet using Text editors within Mac.